# Is it possible to have the built-in Google maps display an address

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps, google-geocoder

When passing coordinates to an Intent to show the location centered in the Google Maps app, is it possible to have it display the address, too, or any kind of label, or are the coordinates the only thing that can be passed/the only way the map can be manipulated?

I know I can use a MapControl and take full control of it, but I'm wondering if I can simply invoke the maps app and show a geocoding of the coordinates passed in as a label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think that you would be able to make any changes in the default maps application. You might want to use map widget by regestering for a mpas api key and build a custom app.

Comment: That's what I thought; I was just hoping the map app offered a little more configurability.